# npm is not working even after installing the node again

Tags: node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\Sahil Mandoliya> npm --version
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I am trying to run npm but it is not working and showing npm.cmd failed to run.

Answer (score 0):

First check npm is installed or not using:-  npm -v
Else update npm using:-   npm install npm@latest -g